# Datalist input appears [object Object] when value is selected - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this part of my form:

```
<div formArrayName="studentPublishing" *ngFor="let all of getstudentPublishing().controls;  index as i">
    <div class="form-group data">
        <input type="text" list="options" class="form-control" placeholder="Students" (change)="getAuthor($event,i)" [formControlName]="i" required>

        <datalist id="options">
        <option *ngFor="let c of dataStudent" [value]="c.name">{{ c.name }}</option>
        </datalist>

        <div class="rem"><button (click)="removeAuthor(i)">-</button></div>

        <div *ngIf="!formPublic.get('studentPublishing')?.valid && formPublic.get('studentPublishing')?.touched" class="validation-error">
            <p>Authors are mandatory</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div id="add" class="add"><button type="button" (click)="addAuthor()">Author +</button></div>
```

Everything is working correctly. The value is the Student object that already comes with the data from the database. My problem here is when I select the Student in the input it shows [object Object].

This is my function in Typescript that takes the value from the data list and writes it to the student array variable of the form:

```
getAuthor(e: any, id:number){
    const studentName = e.target.value;
    const studentSelected = this.dataStudent.find(x => x.name === studentName);
    if (studentSelected) {
      this.getstudentPublishing().at(id).setValue(studentSelected);
    }
}
```

I used ngValue and tried to transform the value with the json pipe:

```
<option *ngFor="let c of dataStudent" [ngValue]="c">{{ c.name | json }}</option>
```

I tried passing the value as a string with the name of the selected object:

```
<option *ngFor="let c of dataStudent" value="{{ c.name }}"></option>
```

But when I save the value in the variable only the name goes and I want the whole object.

This is how the input is looking when a student is selected:

[input datalist image with [object Object]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLR7m.png)

This is how I want it to look to identify which student was selected:

[input datalist image with selected student's name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp0Ar.png)

### Solution

Thanks to Daniel Gimenez's answer I was able to solve my problem.
It came out like this:

```
this.formPublic.updateValueAndValidity();
if(this.formPublic.valid){
  const studentControls = this.getstudentPublishing().controls;
  const students = studentControls.map(y => {
    const name = y.value;
    console.log(name);
    return this.dataStudent.find(student => student.name === name);
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    this.getstudentPublishing().at(i).setValue(students[i]);
    console.log(students[i]?.name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have the FormControl trying to do double duty - Is the value supposed to be a string name or a Student object?  The following is just one of several strategies you can try.

### Make the FormControl elements store string values

In the case each control is of type *FormControl<string>*.  On that control you probably already have a Required Validator, but go ahead and add an existing student name validator.  It can look like this:

```
export function existingStudentValidator(students: Student[]): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const isExisting = students.some(x => x.name === control.value);
    return !isExisting ? { existingStudent: {value: control.value} } : null;
  };
}
```

Now when you need the FormArray value as an array of Student objects, all you have to do is check if the form is in the *valid* state and convert the value by using *Array.map()*.

```
this.form.updateValueAndValidity(); // make sure form validity is up to date.
if (this.form.valid) {
  const students = this.form.studentPublishing.map(x => 
    this.dataStudent.find(y => y.name === x.name)!); // trust that name isn't null.
  /* ... do something with students ... */
}
```

There are a lot of other considerations, like if the name match will be case insensitive or what happens if multiple students have the same name, but this should get you started.

Comment: Yes the value is supposed to be a Student object. Thank you very much I got the result I wanted with some changes to the part about checking if the form is in the valid state as you wrote.